# Securing p12 file

Tags: security, encryption

How can I securely store the p12 file?
As per my knowledge the in p12 file certs are encrypted with RC 40 bits and keys are encrypted with des3 but brute force is the technique which can reveal the password of certs and then same can be used to get the keys and this makes the p12 file bit insecure.
I want my p12 file to be securely stored in the file system.
Can I encrypt this file and store it.If yes, then will the file still be usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PKCS#12 by definition does not define what algorithms are legal to use. PKCS#12 is just a structure of a container for certificates and private keys. That container can be encrypted and signed. See more here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292

Theoretically any encryption could be brute forced. The question is what is the cost and effort to do that successfully. By picking up a trusted algorithms (see the list of NIST approved algorithms for example) you can sleep your night rather well knowing that your private key inside of an encrypted PKCS#12 container would remain safe against brute force.

If your PKCS#12 file uses 3DES encryption it could still be considered safe. See more here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146710/is-the-3des-algorithm-secure

But if you want to restrict access to the PKCS#12 file and the private key inside of it, cheap option would be restricting permissions of the file in the file system. This basically means that only the user running the process have access to that file. More pricier options would be to use hardware tokens and HSMs. Some vendors are SafeNet and Thales for example and you can use those through crypto engines and interfaces such as PKCS#11. The PKCS#12 file could also be protected by a passphrase, which is often recommended if you can tolerate human interactions. In server environments or other use cases where human interaction is not possible, passphrase protected PKCS#12 may be tricky since you need to find a way to protect the passphrase itself.